# problems with buttermilk biscuits

Tags: baking, flour, quickbread

I found the following recipe for buttermilk biscuits:

mix 2c flour, 1tsp salt, 1Tbsp baking soda
cut 6Tbsp cold butter into mix
add 1c buttermilk
pat and fold on floured surface, cut into round biscuits and put in oven

The first time I made it, I used plain white flour. The buttermilk made it wet, but not overly so - it became a very sticky dough.

I recently tried again, but this time I used spelt flour instead. The mixture was significantly "wetter" after adding the buttermilk - so much so that I added some (wheat) flour on top to try to get it to what the previous batch was like. They also didn't rise as much when baked.

What explains the difference? My theory is that spelt has less gluten, so the dough didn't hold the CO2 as well when baking. But does this also explain why the batter was so much "wetter" with the same quantities of flour and buttermilk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In quick breads, as opposed to yeast raised breads, it gelatinized starch that creates the structure of the bread, and holds the leavening.

However, according to my research, most spelt flour (which is in fact a variety of wheat) is whole grain flour, so the bran will interfere with structure development.

My quick research indicates that spelt flour recipes requires less liquid to hydrate than standard wheat flour.  According to [What's Cooking America](http://whatscookingamerica.net/CharlotteBradley/Spelt-Flour.htm), this is because spelt flour is more water soluble than standard wheat flour (I interpret this to mean that the starches in it are).

If you google "spelt biscuits" you will find a variety of recipes that are tuned to its characteristics, such [this one from All Recipes](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/spelt-biscuits/) or this one from [King Arthur](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/spelt-biscuits-recipe).